# Mongoid and Rails: Nested Fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, nested-attributes

I'm using Mongoid and for my app, I have a Course, Section, and Lesson model.
A course has_many sections, a section belongs_to a course and has_many lessons, and a lesson belongs_to a section.  When I try

```
some_course.some_section.lessons.create()
```

I get this error: NoMethodError: undefined method `lessons' for Mongoid::Criteria

I tried doing something like this:

```
#Course.rb 
has_many :sections, -> { includes :lessons }
```

And I get an error: No implicit conversion of Proc into Hash

How might I be able to create a lesson into a section, which is in a course like this:

```
some_course.some_section.lessons.create()
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned, a Course `has_many` sections. So when you do `some_course.sections` you get a `Criteria` (a.k.a a database iterator) to iterate over all the sections that belong to `some_course`. Even when you apply a condition on the `sections` so that it matches only one section, you still get back a `Criteria`.

i.e `some_course.sections.where(id: 'unique_section_id')` returns a criteria. If you want the actual `Section` object use the `first` method on the criteria.

i.e `some_course.sections.where(id: 'unique_section_id').first`

Note that `some_course.sections.first` also works, but you are not always sure which section you will get back.